# Is anything wrong with this PHP-API code?

Tags: php, api, debugging

I've been getting internal server error message just recently and I don't know what's wrong. Can you please tell me what's wrong with this? I wrote CODE for $client_id and $client_secret for security purposes.

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['donation']) && isset($_POST['owner']) && isset($_POST['title'])) {
$owner = $_POST['owner'];
$donation = $_POST['donation'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
if ($donation == "") {
    echo "fail";
} else if ($donation >= 1 && $donation != "" && is_numeric($donation)) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="$owner" AND activated="1" LIMIT 1';
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $access_token = $row["access"];
        $account_id = $row["account_id"];
      }

     require 'wepay.php';
    // application settings
    $client_id = CODE;
    $client_secret = "CODE";    
    // change to useProduction for live environments
    Wepay::useStaging($client_id, $client_secret);

    $wepay = new WePay($access_token);

    // create the checkout
    $response = $wepay->request('checkout/create', array(
        'account_id'        => $account_id,
        'amount'            => ''.$donation.'',
        'short_description' => ''.$title.'',
        'type'              => 'DONATION'
    ));
    echo "all_good";
    // display the response
    print_r($response);
} else {
    echo "unknown";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You should tell us what is wrong and then we can help you :D

Comment: It gives me an internal server error message...

Comment: post the error message

Comment: POST https://domain.com/status.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Then go check the server’s error log …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote it for security purposes? Then read up on mysqli and parameters:
This is is sensitive to sql injection:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="$owner" AND activated="1" LIMIT 1';
```

Should be:
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND activated="1" LIMIT 1';
    $query = mysqli_prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param("i",$owner);

(See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for more examples).

```
if ($donation == "") {
    echo "fail";
} else if ($donation >= 1 && $donation != "" && is_numeric($donation))
```

could just be:

```
if (!is_numeric($donation)) {
    echo "fail";
} else if ($donation >= 1) { etc
```